# Cart items in magento

Tags: php, magento

I want to display the cart items in magento. Currently it's display on the basis on product qty, but I want to display them on number of product added into the cart.

E.g. If I added 1 product of 1kg and other product of 0.500grms then in header displays 1.5 items, I want to display it as 2 items.

Any suggestions? My Magento version is 1.9.0.1

Comment: put that part of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a config setting field under System > Configuration > Sales > Checkout > My Cart Link with two options: "Display number of items in cart" and "Display item quantities". Choose the second option and your displaying issue will be solved.

Comment: thank you piCode for your reply, your solution solves my problem.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 functions available for Item count.

1) Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount() -- return shopping cart items count means how many sku add to shopping cart.

2) Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount() -- return shopping cart items summary (suppose you add sku1 6 qty and sku2 3 qty = total 9 qty return)

You can use 1st function.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation here:

> app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Block\Cart\Minicart.php

Points to a config setting in Magento admin:

> admin/system_config/edit/section/checkout/

**My cart link**

For edge cases you may need to loop through the cart and quantify as desired yourself.